# Pandas: Groupby names in index and columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that uses MultiIndex for both index and columns.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2], [1,2,3], [4,5]], names=['i','j', 'k']), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2], [1,2]], names=['x', 'y']))
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = np.random.randint(100, size=(12,1))

x       1       2
y       1   2   1   2
i j k
1 1 4  10  13   0  76
    5  92  37  52  40
  2 4  88  77  50  22
    5  75  31  19   1
  3 4  61  23   5  47
    5  43  68  10  21
2 1 4  23  15  17   5
    5  47  68   6  94
  2 4   0  12  24  54
    5  83  27  46  19
  3 4   7  22   5  15
    5   7  10  89  79
```

I want to group the values by a name in the index and by a name in the columns.
For each such group, we will have a 2D array of numbers (rather than a Series). I want to aggregate `std()` of all entries in that 2D array.

For example, let's say I groupby `['i', 'x']`, one group would be with values of `i=1` and `x=1`. I want to compute `std` for each of these 2D arrays and produce a `DataFrame` with `i` values as index and `x` values as columns.

What is the best way to achieve this?

If I do `stack()` to get `x` as an index, I will still be computing several `std()` instead of one as there will still be multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehensions. For your example, with the given kind of DataFrame (not the same, as the values are random; you may want to fix a seed value so that results are comparable) and `i` and `x` as the indices of interest, it would work like this:

```
# get values of the top level row index
rows = set(df.index.get_level_values(0))
# get values of the top level column index
columns = set(df.columns.get_level_values(0))

# for every sub-dataframe (every combination of top-level indices) 
# compute sampling standard deviation (1 degree of freedom) across all values
df_groupSD = pd.DataFrame([[df.loc[(row, )][(col, )].values.std(ddof=1)  
                            for col in columns] for row in rows], 
                          index = rows, columns = columns)

# show result
display(df_groupSD)
```

Output:

```
    1           2
1   31.455115   25.433812
2   29.421699   33.748962
```

There may be better ways, of course.

Comment: As there could be many levels in my case and the particular level of interest might not always be at the first, I made this a bit more generic by doing:
`df.xs(1, level='i').xs(1, level='x', axis=1)` instead of the `.loc` based selection. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, and thank you for pointing out the more general solution.

Comment: Another thing I learned is `np.nanstd(values)` could be a better fit in general.

Comment: Good point, you would still want to get a result if just a few values are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` to put the 'y' level of column as index and then `groupby` only i to get:

```
print (df.stack(level='y').groupby(['i']).std())
x          1          2
i                      
1  32.966811  23.933462
2  28.668825  28.541835
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda grp: grp.stack().std())
```